# Why isn't my JSON data showing up in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

I've hit a wall at this point. My json file is connected (I verified in the Chrome console), but it's not showing up on my services.html page. What am I doing wrong? In troubleshooting my issue, I put all of my data in the js file and was able to get it to work, but for obvious reasons, I want to connect my data using a json file. I'm using AngularJS 1.6.2.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    
    // Create module and give it a name
        // also include ngRoute dependency in order to route to different pages
    var makeupApp = angular.module('makeupApp', ['ngRoute']);
    // Configure the routes
    makeupApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl:  'pages/home.html'
            })

            // route for bio page
            .when('/bio', {
                templateUrl:  'pages/bio.html'
            })

            // route for services page
            .when('/services', {
                templateUrl:  'pages/services.html'
            })

            // route for contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl:  'pages/contact.html'
            })
            
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: 'pages/404.html'
            });
    });
    
    makeupApp.controller('PortfolioCtrl', function () {
        this.portfolio = pictures;
        
        pictures = [
            {
                image: 'assets/img/photoshoot.jpg'
            }
        ];
    });
    makeupApp.controller('ServicesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("../assets/services.json").then(function (response) {
            $scope.products = response.data;
        });
    });
})();
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="ServicesCtrl as service">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Services Section-->
        <div id="glam-menu" class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="menu-basic text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3><span class="section-title">General Makeup Application</span></h3>
                        <p>voluptatibus arbitrantur illum illum sunt concursionibus cupidatat possumus 
                            doctrina cillum labore eiusmod fidelissimae quibusdam laborum cupidatat dolor 
                            quem ullamco sed.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-description" ng-repeat="product in service.products">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="pull-left"><strong>{{product.general[0].name}}</strong></div>
                            <div class="pull-right">{{product.general[0].price | currency}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="clearfix"><strong>{{product.general[0].service-description}}</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Services Section-->
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
[{
    "general": [
        {
            "name": "Makeup in the Studio",
            "price": 60,
            "service-description": "quamquam nescius multos quo singulis tamen philosophari cupidatat deserunt offendit veniam te excepteur probant laboris qui in deserunt quid legam"
        },
        {
            "name": "On Location Makeup Service",
            "price": 80,
            "service-description": "Makeup application at the location of the client's choice. Price includes lashes, and travel within a 30 mile radius of the LDM Studio. All makeup at a chair are provided. Supplemental lighting and a table are not provided."
        }
    ],
    "bridal": [
        {
            "name": "Consultations",
            "price": 60,
            "service-description": "1) Price is for a second consultation for the client who has booked services. 2) Price is for first consultation if client does not book services. 3) Price is for a consultation for anyone associated with the bridal party."
        },
        {
            "name": "Blushing Bride",
            "price": 125,
            "service-description": "On Location Makeup Application for your wedding."
        },
        {
            "name": "Bridal Entourage",
            "price": 80,
            "service-description": "On Location Makeup application for anyone associated with the Bride on the Wedding Day."
        },
        {
            "name": "VIP Bride",
            "price": 225,
            "service-description": "On Location Makeup Application and extended stay for touch ups before the ceremony and after the ceremony."
        },
        {
            "name": "Princess Treatment",
            "price": 60,
            "service-description": "On Location Makeup application on Wedding Day for girls under 17 yrs old and under"
        },
        {
            "name": "Celebrity Bride",
            "price": 350,
            "service-description": "On Location Makeup application for your Wedding, and 3 other Wedding related events. Includes one consultation and 30 mile travel."
        },
        {
            "name": "Tattoo Cover",
            "price": 50,
            "service-description": "Starting Price. Pricing depends on size and depth of color. Please contact for more information."
        }
    ],
    "production": [
        {
            "name": "Half Day Rate",
            "price": 250,
            "service-description": "On location makeup services for up to 3.5 hours."
        },
        {
            "name": "Full Day Rate",
            "price": 500,
            "service-description": "On location makeup services for up to 8 hours."
        }
    ],
    "lessons": [
        {
            "name": "Makeup Lesson",
            "price": 125,
            "service-description": "Interactive Lesson suited to client needs. Common elements listed below, but not limited to. I gear it towards your needs and wants. 1) Approx 2 hours. 2) Located at the LDM Studio. 3) Makeup bag analysis. What to keep and what to toss. 4) Feature and color analysis. 5) Techniques to achieve 2 different looks: day and night. 6) Tools and product description and suggestions. 7) False lash application lesson. 8) Hands on and demonstration teaching. 9) Post lesson open door policy. Email me about anything makeup related! Any and all questions will be answered in a timely fashion."
        },
        {
            "name": "Concierge Makeup Shopping",
            "price": 100,
            "service-description": "In addition, for clients who have booked a Lesson. Don't be intimidated by large cosmetics departments or pushy sales people. I will navigate you to the products you need as well as others that you might be interested in investing in later. I will introduce you to people who can assist you in the future with your shopping experience in conjunction with my help. *Travel with client to International Plaza in Tampa, FL to shop for products."
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Controller as Syntax, Change it to **`this.products`**

```
 makeupApp.controller('ServicesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("../assets/services.json").then(function (response) {
            this.products = response.data;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. That's one of the things I tried before.

Comment: the problem is your array contains object inside object. so you need to access the object first.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping properly.
Try ng-repeats like this

```js
           <div class="menu-description" ng-repeat="product in products">
                        <div ng-repeat="p in product['general']">
                          {{ p.name }}
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the link to [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DUjbqXGj9xxED12ZfC2x?p=preview)